# Accessing Google AAID via Mobile Browser (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, google-advertising-id

I've been searching online for sometime now and have yet to find a clear answer on this subject.

I would like to access a users Google AAID (Advertising ID) via my website when they access it using a mobile browser. I would think this would be possible with some javascript code but I have yet to find any.

Has anyone had experience with this? And is it possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Capturing IDFA/GAID from mobiles browsers cannot be done, 
Apply this approach in native or hybrid app.
until today PWA also do not support
[How to fetch device information from a progressive web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889869/how-to-fetch-device-information-from-a-progressive-web-app/55472757#55472757)