# How to fetch device information from a progressive web app

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-website, progressive-web-apps, idfa, google-advertising-id

How to fetch device information (Google Advertising Id or IDFA) from a progressive web app

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: Did you get any clues for the question, me too searching for the same..

Answer (score 4):

[Google Advertising ID is not accessible](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-capture-Google-Advertising-ID-from-a-mobile-browser-on-Android) to progressive web app running in browser and so the installed PWA.

Said that, you can make it available to your installed PWA using an Android service(which is a native code getting the Google Advertising ID) and passing it to your [PWA using Deep link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen#android_intent_filters)s, by setting a Indent filter to your PWA with a URL and have the ID retrieved in your native code passed to web app in the query para (URL).

You can refer to this [java code](https://developers.tune.com/sdk/passing-native-device-identifiers-to-javascript/#code-platform-android) to retrieve device identifiers and wrap it as a Android service, which calls your PWA using deep links.