# get IMEI number from Device in angular - 8

Tags: angular, angular8, imei

I am new to **angular-8**

currently i m working on one application in **angular-8**
there

i need **(IMEI)** number of the perticular **device**

> (not in the native app i need in PWA(Progressive WebApp) i will use it mobile phones like IOS,Android)

can anyone help with this

Thank you in adavnce

Comment: so from a webapp ? you can't, you need a native app for that

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Pac0 sorry but this is not the answer.

Comment: can you elaborate on why the linked Q&A doesn't answer the question ? The underlying problem is not with Angular. It's because an Angular app is a web app, probably opened in a browser, and the browser won't let you get this information.

Comment: (not in the native app i need in PWA(Progressive WebApp) i will use it mobile phones like IOS,Android)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help i think it looks like it will help for me...@Pac0

Comment: Thanks for the PWA precision. Maybe this Q&A has interesting link as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164662/is-there-a-way-for-pwas-to-access-the-phone-number-of-the-host-device

Comment: I got the answer for my question thanks for the help@Pac0