# Track user by IDFA / GAID on a web-site

Tags: idfa, google-advertising-id

I want to achieve the following ( mobile users only ):
- if user clicks on a link he receives, he goes to my web-site
- if this user then downloads my app from google play / apple store, I will offer him some discounted price

I am thinking to implement it by tracking user's IDFA or GAID. I know that it's 100% possible to get on mobile app ( so the 2nd step is 100% ).

However, I wonder if it's possible to get IDFA / GAID on my web-site ( like that I can make an ajax request to the server to memorize IDFA / GAID so later on I will give discounted price to this mobile ).

Are there any clues?

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Capturing IDFA/GAID from mobiles browsers cannot be done, both Android and iOS only support thru either Hybrid or native app, I thought of similar scenario thru PWA's , but resorted to implementing in Hybrid app, 
here is support docs,
https://support.google.com/authorizedbuyers/answer/3221407?hl=en

http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html

I thought this approach would do, but this one also points to implementing in native app.
[How to fetch device information from a progressive web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889869/how-to-fetch-device-information-from-a-progressive-web-app/55472757#55472757)